# What was the name for a Choose your own adventure style book in space?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space, choose-your-own-adventure

It's a Choose your own adventure style book in space. There were certain scenes where you were a tyro in space and you had to train in an antigravity room with other newbies. A scene where you were in a ship by the rings of Saturn and you had to pick whether to go through them or around them. I also believe you get to Earth perhaps on a train. Not sure about the earth part but I am really sure about the space parts of the book. I read it sometime in the 90s I believe.

Comment: Please check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if that helps jog your memory.

Comment: What is a tyro?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_(novel_series) - CYOA "The Rings of Saturn"?

Comment: Interplanetary Spy series?  About how many pages between pictures (if any)?  Interplanetary Spy series is picture heavy

Comment: Yes it was "The Rings of Saturn" ! Thanks @Valorum, you guys are awesome.  Didn't think it would be answered this fast. Oh and about the word "tyro", the first I heard of that word was in this book which is why I used the same word haha.

Comment: @Valorum next one in the fightingfantasy channel?

Comment: @Edlothiad - I'm not a fan of these CYOA books. They're a bit junior

Comment: @valorum, ok we'll stick with yours :rolls_eyes:

Comment: @MiguelRivera - Don't forget to click the "accepted" button.

Answer (score 10):

This is the Choose Your Own Adventure book "[The Rings of Saturn"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_(novel_series)), part of the Time Machine series. Tyros are trainee *'Time Astronauts'*

> *Once tyros arrive at the academy. You still may be on Earth. This must be how you learn how to move in outer space. You begin learning how to think like an astronaut. “Move those legs and shake those arms!” Padgett shouts from above. You sink. Like a feather drifting to the ground. You can even go up. The other tyros gleefully leap into the pool.*

[image]